# #1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

Tags: mysql, cpanel

**Hello, I am currently having an issue with MySQL!**

What's going wrong here? I am a *cPanel* user, and yes I have searched this and found no definitive answers. It appears this is more specific than other people with the same error codes issues. Please add a detailed response that I can follow along with! P.s I am using a shared hosting account.

```
DELIMITER $$--
-- Functions
--
CREATE DEFINER =  `root`@`localhost` FUNCTION  `fnc_calcWalkedDistance` (

`steamid64` BIGINT UNSIGNED
) RETURNS INT( 10 ) UNSIGNEDNO SQL BEGIN DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE distance INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE x1, x2, z1, z2 FLOAT;

DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR SELECT x, z
FROM log_positions
WHERE  `steamid` = steamid64
ORDER BY  `timestamp` DESC ;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished =1;

OPEN curs;

FETCH curs INTO x1, z1;

SET x2 = x1;

SET z2 = z1;

calculate : LOOPFETCH curs INTO x1, z1;

IF finished =1 THEN LEAVE calculate;

END IF ;

SET distance = distance + SQRT( POW( x2 - x1, 2 ) + POW( z2 - z1, 2 ) ) ;

-- SET distance = distance + 1;
SET x2 = x1;

SET z2 = z1;

END LOOP calculate;

CLOSE curs;

RETURN distance;

END$$
```

**Here is the error code:**

```
MySQL said: Documentation

#1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation
```

Answer (score 85, accepted):

It means you don't have privileges to create the trigger with **root@localhost** user..

try removing definer from the trigger command:

CREATE ***DEFINER =  `root`@`localhost`*** FUNCTION  `fnc_calcWalkedDistance`

Comment: I dump my database to sql file, I don't remember to create any function like this... Searching on dump file, I found on last line this commands, I remove and works, thanks.

Comment: Thanks, in my case I fixed it by renaming `root`@`localhost to `serverusername`@`localhost`

Comment: Just replace root with database login name

Answer (score 42):

Simply remove "DEFINER=`your user name`@`localhost`" and run the SQL from phpmyadminwill works fine.

Comment: It worked, that's a perfect answer. And GoDaddy told me that I should purchase a dedicated server for this, but you saved my day.

Comment: Otherwise, change the username to already all permission granted username.

Answer (score 23):

In case you are uploading an sql file on cpanel, then try and replace root with your cpanel username in your sql file.

in the case above you could write

CREATE DEFINER =  `control_panel_username`@`localhost` FUNCTION  `fnc_calcWalkedDistance`

then upload the file.
Hope it helps

Comment: yep it was control_panel_user@localhost for me

Answer (score 7):

remove DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` from all calls including procedures

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
CREATE DEFINER =  `root`@`localhost` FUNCTION  `fnc_calcWalkedDistance` (
```

By

```
FUNCTION  `fnc_calcWalkedDistance` (
```

Answer (score 0):

Either remove the line `CREATE DEFINER =  root@localhost` or change it to `CREATE DEFINER =  <mysqluser>@<mysqlhost>`

If you delete the DEFINER attribute, the default will be the current user account.

Note: `DEFINER` is an optional attribute for defining a stored procedure or function.