# mysql showing error #1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

Tags: mysql, cpanel

tried

`SET GLOBAL max_connections = 1024;`

to change maximum number of connections its showing

> 1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation.

now Bigrock is telling me that I have to get a dedicated server to be able to increase maximum connections. [I'm using a linux shared hosting]
is there any other way?

Comment: if you really need to increase that value either: your application is big enough for dedicated resource or you have some errors in your architecture that are leading to a connection overhead

Comment: already answered see this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31315660/1227-access-denied-you-need-at-least-one-of-the-super-privileges-for-thi

Comment: Does this answer your question? [#1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31315660/1227-access-denied-you-need-at-least-one-of-the-super-privileges-for-thi)

Comment: @MamunMalik sorry, but could you tell how to increase maximmum-no-of-connections?

Comment: @JavierG.Raya this certainly doesnot answer my question.

Comment: @LelioFaieta ` ` ` SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "max_connections"; ` ` ` shows 150 connections max. but I need more than that.

Comment: Your service provider offered you the option of moving to a dedicated host. That's their requirement if you need more database connections. This is clearly not a code issue.

Answer (score 0):

To permanently increase max connections, open my.cnf file,

```
sudo vi /etc/my.cnf
```

Depending on your Linux distribution and type of installation, my.cnf file may be located at any of the following locations.

```
/etc/my.cnf
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
$MYSQL_HOME/my.cnf
~/.my.cnf
```

Add the following line under [mysqld] section.

```
max_connections = 200
```

Now if you restart MySQL server, the changes will persist.